# How to add a tag with the message taken from the last commit

Tags: git, commit, git-log, git-tag

I need to add a new tag and the message I need it to be the message of the last commit.

For example, let's suppose I have the following commit:

```
git commit -m "refactored that module"
```

The I would create a tag like this:

```
git tag -a 1.2.3 -m "refactored that module"
```

I would want to not copy/paste the last message.

Answer (score 0):

The command that automatically takes the message from the last commit is:

```
git log -1 --format=%B
```

Then, we must pass that message to our `git tag -a` command, like this:

```
git tag -a 2.1.3 -m "$(git log -1 --format=%B)"
```

We must replace `2.1.3` with our desired version number.